# Find fieldId through labelid

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I would like ask if it is possible to find the fieldId of a specific table through the labelId of the field.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this for getting a list of all fields (and tables) that references a particular label ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible solutions:

```
static void FindTableFieldsByLabel(Args _args)
{
    TableId         tableId     = tableNum(AccountingDistribution);
    str             findLabel   = literalStr('@SYS132687');
    SysDictTable    dictTable;
    SysDictField    dictField;
    FieldId         fieldId;

    dictTable   = new SysDictTable(tableId);
    fieldId     = dictTable.fieldNext(0);

    while (fieldId)
    {
        dictField = dictTable.fieldObject(fieldId);

        if (dictField.isSql() && !dictField.isSystem()
            && dictField.labelLabel() == findLabel)
        {
            info(strFmt('Field name: %1', dictField.name()));
        }

        fieldId = dictTable.fieldNext(fieldId);
    }

    info('Job completed');
}
```

You can also use `dictField.labelDefined()` if you want to ignore the labels set on extended data types and not on the table fields.

Answer (score 3):

Use Cross Reference. Via interface:

1. Tools \ Label \ Label Editor
2. Enter LabelID in `Find what` field
3. Click on `Used by` button
4. Find Tables, Maps or Views in the list

You sould generate Cross reference before (Tools \ Cross reference \ Periodic \ Update)

[image: Used by]

Comment: A good approach if the label is used on the table field directly (maybe that's exactly what @Nikos Kou needs), and not on an extended data type or an enum used by the table field.

Comment: See more crossrefs if a label used on the EDT, enum, report, form, confkey and other AOT objects. Use button `Add-ins \ Cross-reference \ Used by` to continue exploring deeper